# Batch File Del - Could Not Find

Tags: batch-file, del

I've got two commands. The first one works just fine but the second one doesn't. I keep getting the error, "Could Not Find..." even though the file does in fact exist there. Why won't the del work but the echo will? I'm trying to delete all files in that path with an extension of .jpg.

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\hi\Desktop\test" /m *.jpg /d -1 /c "cmd /c echo @path @fdate"
pause

forfiles /p "C:\Users\hi\Desktop\test" /m *.jpg /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path @srchmask"
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why won't the `del` work but the `echo` will?

`echo` will just output whatever you tell it to.

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\hi\Desktop\test" /m *.jpg /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path @srchmask"
```

The above command is incorrect. There is no "Command Variable" called `@srchmask` defined for the to `forfiles` command:

```
Command Variables:
  @file    The name of the file.
  @fname   The file name without extension.                
  @ext     Only the extension of the file.                  
  @path    Full path of the file.
  @relpath Relative path of the file.          
  @isdir   Returns "TRUE" if a file type is a directory,
           and "FALSE" for files.
  @fsize   Size of the file in bytes.
  @fdate   Last modified date of the file.
  @ftime   Last modified time of the file.
```

Source [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).

You already have `/m *.jpg` specified as a "searchmask" for your `forfiles` command, so I'm not sure what you intended to do with `@srchmask`. You could try just removing it...

You should also read up on the syntax for [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) in case you needs some other options instead of `@srchmask`...

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) - Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.

Comment: For @srchmask the intention was to say something like go to that path and delete any file there with the ext .jpg. This is how I originally had it but was still getting the could not find error. 
forfiles /p "C:\Users\hi\Desktop\test" /m *.jpg /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path"